# How to run pygame in the background?

Tags: pygame, background

I made a small pygame app that plays certain wav files in keypress using pygame.mixer
All seem to work just fine except the fact that if you minimize the pygame window the program stops working until you open it again. Is there a way to solve this issue or an alternative way to implement sound playing in python?

This is my repository: https://github.com/Souvlaki42/HighPlayer

Comment: You don’t need to have a window open to use pygame.mixer

Comment: I know but for some reason my app doesn't work when I minimize or close it.

Comment: That sounds like something your operating system would do, so I'm not sure a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pygame.mixer.music()` but you'll need to convert all your wav files into mp3 files.

Comment: But, keyboard inputs are not available when the window is closed.

Comment: You could try making a transparent window

Comment: I tried to convert all my wav files to mp3 and still it isn't working when I minimize the window. Are there any ways to detect input and play sounds using pygame when I minimize or run the "game" in the background? Also I don't think a transparent window will solve my problems because I want to allow user continue working with something else and if he wants to press any of the numbers to play custom sounds.

Comment: What i mean is that transparent window when the window is minimised

Comment: This way the functions in the window can run in the transparent window

Comment: The Pygame documentation says that:

"If the display has not been initialized and a video mode not set, the event queue will not really work." https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html

Comment: After much research, I found pyautogui

Comment: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: This way you can receive keyboard inputs with screen minimised

Comment: ok thanks i will check it and i will write again

Comment: We have a problem. I installed pyautogui, I imported it, I replaced if event.key == pygame.K_1: with if pyautogui.press("num1"): and now the event don't work and also if i try to change something in the file while is running it writes numbers by itself there I try to weite. I did something wrong?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Use this keyboard module:
https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/
I sincerely apologise for the inconvenience caused

Comment: `event = keyboard.read_event()

    if event.event_type == keyboard.KEY_DOWN and event.name == '1':

        playsound(1)`

Comment: If you want, you can also try to use hotkeys function in pyautogui

Comment: Also pyautogui.press() will press the button for you, not the other way round.

Comment: Well, it worked but know I need a new way of playing audio files in wav or mp3 format. Do you have any ways except playaudio and pygame modules?

Comment: The following are 3 methods (not including playsound module): https://pythonbasics.org/python-play-sound/

Comment: Not of them don't work please help me...

Comment: Sry, can you correct your grammar, I can't understand you.

Comment: Also tell me what error occurred

Comment: https://realpython.com/playing-and-recording-sound-python/

Comment: Sorry, I meant none of them actually worked each for different reasons but I remember that when I was trying to install a python module including TKinter and tkSnack I got this error:                                                                                                                     Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement TKinter (from versions: none)
No matching distribution found for TKinter

Comment: tkinter is preinstalled if you use the compiler from python.org

Comment: try using this command:
`pip install tk`

Comment: requirement already satisfied is the output of pip install tk

Comment: that means tkinter is already installed

Answer (score 0):

Just patch up all my mistakes your code  from line 34 onwards should now be:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    event2 = keyboard.read_event()
    if event2.name == pygame.K_0:
        stopSounds()
        sound0.play()
    if event2.name == pygame.K_1:
        stopSounds()
        sound1.play()
    if event2.name == pygame.K_2:
        stopSounds()
        sound2.play()
    if event2.name == pygame.K_3:
        stopSounds()
        sound3.play()
    if event2.name == pygame.K_4:
        stopSounds()
        sound4.play()
    if event2.name == pygame.K_5:
        stopSounds()
        sound5.play()
    if event2.name == pygame.K_6:
        stopSounds()
        sound6.play()
    if event2.name == pygame.K_7:
        stopSounds()
        sound7.play()
    if event2.name == pygame.K_8:
        stopSounds()
        sound8.play()
    if event2.name == pygame.K_9:
        stopSounds()
        sound9.play()
```